# Handle files from ftp:// and file://

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'll make a program that can collect files from anywhere. In the configuration, I should be able to enter filpattern in following forms:

```
c:\aaa\bbb\cc\aaa*.txt
ftp://user:password@host/ddd/eee/*.dat
```

Is there any class in .NET that can handle both these cases, or do I have to handle ftp:// and file:// separately?

**Edit:**

I also have to remove them after I've read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) with your URL. That will return a class derived from `WebRequest` of the appropriate type. You can detect the actual type and cast appropriately to handle the different download protocols. It understands the following URL schemes:

- `http://`
- `https://`
- `ftp://`
- `file://`

Comment: Is it posible to use * in the URL to get all files that match the pattern?